# Question about root of the name of the cartoon " Wet Blanket Policy"

Tags: word-meaning

I know that is the name of a famous cartoon. I have not ever seen this motion picture, I was wondering if anybody, not necessarily have seen it, could help me out, determining whether it is an idiom. Could it perhaps mean " a tendency to be a wet blanket " ?

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_Blanket_Policy#References)</sub>
>
> The title [Wet Blanket Policy] is a play-on-words about a type of insurance policy.

It's a combination of the idiom *wet blanket* and the insurance term *blanket policy*.

- [*Wet blanket*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wet+blanket) refers to a person who spoils other people's enjoyment.
- [*Blanket policy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanket_policy) is an insurance that *covers* more than one type of property.